# How to apply drop cap css on second line of paragraph

Tags: css

I have text as given below:---

---

Hello Team,

This is the greeting of the day,that we are going to launch a new phone in market. Simply insert this code at the beginning of the first paragraph of your article. Of course, you can tweak it per your needs.

The problem with this method is that it's a lot of code to have to insert for each and every article.

---

So i want to apply drop cap to only second line`s first letter (i.e. T). how to do that?

In this message all three line written in three different-diffrent p tags.

Thanks,

Comment: Drop cap is a style sheet notation in which we can make first letter of a line in a different style.

refere: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-better-paragraph/

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot add a class to the second line?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [**link**](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3888236) with complete instructions.

In HTML it's basically achieved selecting pseudo elements.

More info about [**pseudo elements**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp).

Comment: try to avoid `link only` answers. This answer will become invalid once the link is broken. So include the helpful code snippet here and use links as reference.

Comment: The external link in the first line in this answer does not work. As @PrasanthKC forecasted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

do like  this:

```
p:first-letter{
    font-size:300%;
    float:left;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

[image]

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/4DYRJ/1/) - 
[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/4DYRJ/3/) - 
[**Simple Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/4DYRJ/4/)

Comment: yes perfect but i wanted to make drop cap in second line`s first character. Thanks

Comment: you can not do it, CSS couldn't recognize that line two starts with which character unless you put that character into a tag. for example `<span>` then you can style that character. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/4DYRJ/5/)